# zelig package in R gives the same standard error with robust=TRUE

Tags: r, robust, probit

Any idea why robust option is not working in Zelig package?

```
        library(AER)
        data(Affairs)
        mydata<-Affairs
        mydata$affairs<-with(mydata,ifelse(affairs>0,1,affairs)) # convert to 1 and 0 
        library(Zelig)
        probit1<-zelig(affairs ~ gender+ age + yearsmarried + children + religiousness+education + rating, model = "logit", data = mydata,robust=FALSE)
        probit2<-zelig(affairs ~ gender+ age + yearsmarried + children + religiousness+education + rating, model = "logit", data = mydata,robust=TRUE)

        > summary(probit1)

     Call:
glm(formula = formula, weights = weights, family = binomial(link = "probit"), 
    model = F, data = data)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-1.5112  -0.7642  -0.5744  -0.2214   2.5736  

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)    0.76416    0.51572   1.482 0.138416    
gendermale     0.18882    0.13052   1.447 0.148000    
age           -0.02440    0.01053  -2.318 0.020460 *  
yearsmarried   0.05461    0.01880   2.904 0.003683 ** 
childrenyes    0.20807    0.16373   1.271 0.203790    
religiousness -0.18609    0.05193  -3.583 0.000339 ***
education      0.01551    0.02652   0.585 0.558731    
rating        -0.27271    0.05338  -5.109 3.25e-07 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 675.38  on 600  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 610.50  on 593  degrees of freedom
AIC: 626.5

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4

summary(probit2)
Call:
glm(formula = formula, weights = weights, family = binomial(link = "probit"), 
    model = F, data = data)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-1.5112  -0.7642  -0.5744  -0.2214   2.5736  

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)    0.76416    0.51572   1.482 0.138416    
gendermale     0.18882    0.13052   1.447 0.148000    
age           -0.02440    0.01053  -2.318 0.020460 *  
yearsmarried   0.05461    0.01880   2.904 0.003683 ** 
childrenyes    0.20807    0.16373   1.271 0.203790    
religiousness -0.18609    0.05193  -3.583 0.000339 ***
education      0.01551    0.02652   0.585 0.558731    
rating        -0.27271    0.05338  -5.109 3.25e-07 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 675.38  on 600  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 610.50  on 593  degrees of freedom
AIC: 626.5

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4
```